# c# HttpListener behind router

Tags: c#, .net, webserver, router, httplistener

I have a web sever embebed in an application, very similar to [this](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/ShowPost.aspx?id=3748). But i have problems with i try access behind a router. I think code is right because if i change host file, all is working.

Can anybody explain what is the problem?

Comment: What exceptions/symptoms are you experiencing?

Comment: What port is the server listening on? And what IP address? Is that address routable by your router? This seems to be more of a networking problem than programming.

Comment: Then, do you use HttpListener behind a router? I have seen other embebed servers and all are using TcpListener

Comment: It was a network problem, i don´t know what is. But it works in other computers. Thx to all.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set up port forwarding on the router to the machine hosting your site for the specific port you are trying to connect to from outside?

Comment: I know, I know. The router is correctly set up, and I´m using the same port internal and external because this code has some problem with prefix.

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your firewall isn't blocking?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do port forwarding on the router.  This is a common problem with bit-torrent clients, so if you want to learn how to do it help files for those applications are quite good.